# how get real mac-address?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have many virtual network adapter and I need get real mac-address.
this code give me list of mac-address but how i can identify real or virtual network adapter?

```
var macAddr =
            (
                from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm curious what you want the mac address for, and why you want to discern physical NICs from virtual NICs.

Comment: i need get physical-address of physical-network adapter. i don't need virtual.i have a software in client side and i want send this mac-address for server and using that for identify the machine. i know how get other hardware-ID but i need real mac-address. pls help me